# finding which epoch timestamp is the largest in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Without using time functions, would the correct way of calculating which EPOCH time is the greatest be sufficient to use a function like:

```
times = [1617315161, 1617315162, 1617315164, 1617315163]
latest_time = times[0]

for each in range(0, len(times):
    if (times[each] > latest_time):
       latest_time = times[each]

print("latest EPOCH time is: " + str(latest_time))
```

or is there a better way to compare epoch times?

Few of you have mentioned EPOCH is just an integer. My question...is it safe to assume the max EPOC time stamp is always the latest time?

Comment: They are just integers.  What's wrong with `max(times)`?

Comment: this is simply a comparison between numbers, so ur code is working, u want another algorithm or what exactly?

Comment: I'm going to have a list of dicts actually, there is more to just the timestamp. I would need to know that for the max time stamp take that dict and extract the additional metadata

Comment: The word "epoch" usually refers to the base point for some set of data.  What you have there are Unix `time_t` values, which are integer seconds since January 1, 1970.  For `time_t` values, 1/1/1970 is the "epoch".

Comment: You can `max` over your list of dicts and pass in a `key=lambda d: d['timestamp']` keyword-argument (or something similar). That way you can still extract the rest of the data.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
times = [1617315161, 1617315162, 1617315163]
print("latest EPOCH time is: " + str(max(times)))
```

or even better:

```
times = [1617315161, 1617315162, 1617315163]
print(f"latest EPOCH time is: {max(times)}")
```

UPD:

> is it safe to assume the max EPOC time stamp is always the latest time?

Yes, since it's just a number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970. Even if you'll have a good mix of different formats there (s, ms) - max() is going to return the latest anyway (the most precise one).